# Only last row is coming with export pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am trying to export a html table to pdf, I am able to generate the pdf file successfuly but only the last row is coming. I am using `tcpdf` to implement this.
I am using the following code:

```
$tbl1='<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%" style="text-align:center;" border="1">
<tr style="font-weight:500;">
<td height="35">Deal Id</td>
<td>Deal Title</td>
<td>Deal Offer Id </td>
<td>No. Of Purchases</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Total Price</td>
<td>Date</td>
</tr>';
$tbl1.='<tr style="align="center">
    <td>sss</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr><tr style="align="center">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>';
$tbl1.='</table>';
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl1, true, 0, true, 0);
    $pdf->Output('Deal-wise-report.pdf', 'D');
```

Here is the result:
[image]

If I try to echo the `$tbl1` I am getting two rows

Comment: where you are running your php query ?

Comment: In the local xampp server

Comment: see my answer...and try to do it..

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in style syntax, should be:

```
<tr style="align: center;">
```

Comment: ;) few seconds delay between posting this error...But css doesn't have style="align:center;" either

Comment: True, this should be text-align: center;

Comment: I have removed the styling from `tr` but still only one row is coming

Comment: So does not td height="35", this should be td style="height: 35px;"

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr style="align="center">
```

Should be

```
<tr align="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
   $tbl1='<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%" style="text-align:center;" border="1">
<tr style="font-weight:500;">
<td>Deal Id</td>
<td>Deal Title</td>
<td>Deal Offer Id </td>
<td>No. Of Purchases</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Total Price</td>
<td>Date</td>
</tr>';
$tbl1.='<tr>
    <td>sss</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>';
$tbl1.='</table>';
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl1, true, 0, true, 0);
    $pdf->Output('Deal-wise-report.pdf', 'D');
```